# Simplest way to perform logging from Google Cloud Run

Tags: python, docker, logging, google-cloud-run

I followed this guide https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run to setup cloud run docker.
Then I tried to follow this guide https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/logging to perform a simple log. Trying to write a structured log to stdout
This is my code:

```
    trace_header = request.headers.get('X-Cloud-Trace-Context')

    if trace_header:
        trace = trace_header.split('/')
        global_log_fields['logging.googleapis.com/trace'] = "projects/sp-64d90/traces/" + trace[0]

    # Complete a structured log entry.
    entry = dict(severity='NOTICE',
                 message='This is the default display field.',
                 # Log viewer accesses 'component' as jsonPayload.component'.
                 component='arbitrary-property',
                 **global_log_fields)

    print(json.dumps(entry))
```

I cannot see this log in the Cloud Logs Viewer. I do see the http Get logs each time I call the docker.
Am I missing anything? I am new to this and wondered what is the simples way to be able to log information and view it assuming the docker I created was exactly with the steps from the guide (https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run)

Thanks

Comment: Look in Stackdriver -> Logs Viewer -> Cloud Run Revision. Select All logs. Your print() should appear there. Anything written to stdout or stderr will be logged as unstructured data after a couple of minutes.

Comment: John Hanley that is exactly what I did and I do not see it. I do see a new log entry for every http get request to the service but no additional entries

Comment: Is there anything special I need to add to my Dockerfile maybe? All I want is to see the outputs of a simple "print" to stdout, thanks again.

Comment: Nothing additional is required for Cloud Run. Try a regular Python `print('Hello world')`. That should show up in Stackdriver.

Comment: So this is exactly what I did and I cannot see the logs :(

Comment: Yeah, same exact issue in a VM. I can enter "logger('TEST')" on the command line and see TEST show up in the Logs Viewer almost immediately, but there is no way to log anything from Python.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am running into the exact same issue. I did find that flushing stdout causes the logging to appear when it otherwise would not. Looks like a bug in Cloud Run to me.

```
print(json.dumps(entry))
import sys
sys.stdout.flush()
```

[Output with flushing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qt0v2.png)

Comment: A better solution is setting `ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True` in your `Dockerfile` to disable output buffering entirely.

Answer (score 9):

#For Python/Java

Using "google-cloud-logging" module is the easiest way to push container logs to Stackdriver logs. COnfigure google-cloud-logging to work with python's default logging module

```
import logging as log
import google.cloud.logging as logging

def doSomething(param):
    logging_client = logging.Client()
    logging_client.setup_logging()
log.info(f"Some log here: {param}")
```

now you should see this log in Stackdriver logging under Cloud Run Revision.

Comment: [official docs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/python)

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to integrate Google Cloud Platform logging into your Python code is to create a subclass from `logging.StreamHandler`. This way logging levels will also match those of Google Cloud Logging, enabling you to filter based on severity. This solution also works within Cloud Run containers.

Also you can just add this handler to any existing logger configuration, without needing to change current logging code.

```py
import json
import logging
import os
import sys
from logging import StreamHandler

from flask import request


class GoogleCloudHandler(StreamHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        StreamHandler.__init__(self)

    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)
        # Get project_id from Cloud Run environment
        project = os.environ.get('GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT')

        # Build structured log messages as an object.
        global_log_fields = {}
        trace_header = request.headers.get('X-Cloud-Trace-Context')

        if trace_header and project:
            trace = trace_header.split('/')
            global_log_fields['logging.googleapis.com/trace'] = (
                f"projects/{project}/traces/{trace[0]}")

        # Complete a structured log entry.
        entry = dict(severity=record.levelname, message=msg)
        print(json.dumps(entry))
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

A way to configure and use the handler could be:

```py
def get_logger():
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    if not logger.handlers:
        gcp_handler = GoogleCloudHandler()
        gcp_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        gcp_formatter = logging.Formatter(
            '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s [%(filename)s:%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s')
        gcp_handler.setFormatter(gcp_formatter)
        logger.addHandler(gcp_handler)
    return logger
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Follow the guide you mentioned [Serve dynamic content and host microservices with Cloud Run](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run)

2.Add the following code to `index.js`

```
 const {Logging} = require('@google-cloud/logging');
 const express = require('express');
 const app = express();

 app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log('Hello world received a request.');

  const target = process.env.TARGET || 'World';
  const projectId = 'your-project';
  const logging = new Logging({projectId});

  // Selects the log to write to
  const log = logging.log("Cloud_Run_Logs");

  // The data to write to the log
  const text = 'Hello, world!';

  // The metadata associated with the entry
  const metadata = {
    resource: {type: 'global'},
    // See: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry#logseverity
    severity: 'INFO',
  };

  // Prepares a log entry
  const entry = log.entry(metadata, text);

   async function writeLog() {
    // Writes the log entry
    await log.write(entry);
    console.log(`Logged the log that you just created: ${text}`);
  }
  writeLog();




  res.send(`Hello ${target}!`);
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Hello world listening on port', port);
});
```

3.Check the logs under Logging/Global

[image]

## Edit

For python:

```
import os
import google.cloud.logging
import logging


from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    target = os.environ.get('TARGET', 'World')
    # Instantiates a client
    client = google.cloud.logging.Client()

    # Connects the logger to the root logging handler; by default this captures
    # all logs at INFO level and higher
    client.setup_logging()

    # The data to log
    text = 'Hello, these are logs from cloud run!'

    # Emits the data using the standard logging module
    logging.warning(text)
    return 'Hello {}!\n'.format(text)
```

[image]

Comment: I do not use index.js but an app.py in python. I followed this guide to run a docker - https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run. When I implement functions in index.js I actually see the logs, but I cannot see logs from my app.py that implements the docker endpoint.

Answer (score -1):

There is support for Bunyan and Winston node.js libraries in Google Cloud Loggging:

- https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/nodejs#using_bunyan
- https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/nodejs#using_winston

Typically, if you are not looking to do **structured logging**, all you need to do is print things to stdout/stderr and Cloud Run will pick it up.

This is documented at https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/logging and it has Node.js example for structured and non-structured logging as well.

Comment: That is exactly what I thought, but I cannot see outputs of even the simplest "print".

Comment: That sounds odd. Make sure your program is actually not buffering output or something like that. I deploy many apps on Cloud Run and the output of stdout/stderr is always there. Maybe try deploying the sample `gcr.io/cloudrun/hello` app and if that also doesn't collect any logs, contact Google Cloud support.