# Where can I find python print statements in Cloud Run docker instances?

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

If I am running a container within Cloud Run and do a print statement in my python code. Where can I view it? Cloud logs seem to show logs for the contain itself(build, etc)?

to debug my code often I do write statements that help me figure what's going on. Where would that print output be located?

Comment: Everything logged to stdout/stderr should be sent to Cloud Logging. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60828641/simplest-way-to-perform-logging-from-google-cloud-run for a possible explanation

Comment: @DazWilkin thank you. I guess during dev I like to use print statements or something simple. This isn't for production logging or something..it's just to check the value of a variable. I'm curious where the outputs of a run actually go?

Comment: `print` statements go to stdout and are logged by Cloud Logging. However, in the referenced question, there's an issue with needing to flush stdout in order to have the logs displayed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1] You can find all the logs including your print statement output in Cloud Logging as mentioned in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/logging#container-logs). So when you write a print statement from your service they will be automatically picked up by Cloud Logging.

2] [Steps to view logs in Cloud Logging](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/logging#viewing-logs-cloud-logging): Logs Explorer -> Cloud Run Revision.

3] You may wanna check your logging level. For example: if you have configured level as logging.ERROR in basicConfig (default is WARNING), and used logging.info() in your code, then it will not be printed. You can refer to this [link](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html) for more information.

4] Also, you may try flushing the stdout which will make sure the logs get written from buffers. You may refer [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61024169/15774177) on how to do this.